# Append an single Value in 2D element in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I want to just append 1 in the first index of the 2D array, but why the all element of array will be appended by 1 ?

```
num_count = [[]]*5
num_count[0].append(1)
print(num_count)

output : [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

My expected answer is [[1], [], [], [], []]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you define a list like `num_count = [[]]*5`  this puts the same list in all five places in the container list

```py
num_count = [[]]*5
for sub in num_count:
    print(id(sub))
```

output is

```sh
id of sublist is 140592936606336
id of sublist is 140592936606336
id of sublist is 140592936606336
id of sublist is 140592936606336
id of sublist is 140592936606336
```

they are all on the same list.

so to avoid this kind of issue you can use list comprehension.

`num_count = [[] for _ in range(5)]`

now if you add an element in 0 positions it will only append in the 0 positions.

```py
num_count = [[] for _ in range(5)]
num_count[0].append(1)
print(num_count)
```

output is

`[[1], [], [], [], []]`